# edit or modify crystal report within vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

how can i edit crystal report within vb.net application.
let me explain in deep.

i have an application for student management, i have use crystal report for reporting and now i deploy that app. everything it working completely, now different-different user have different-different requirement for reporting. now i want to provide and facility to the end user to edit or modify the crystal report within my .net application.

can it is Possible?

if it is possible than describe the whole process for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such designer for crystal report that you can invoke at run time and enable your users to design reports.

Look for alternative approaches and make your and everyone's life easy :)

1. Install crystal reports for each user who want to create reports. But this may involve licensing.
2. Identify users' current and future requirements in details and based on these provide them generic type of reports with well designed filters and formats.
3. Design your reports in way where users' can customize the format i.e., whatever columns they want to see or hide.

One more thing, whatever business user asks is not always right or the best choice so educate users' for better solutions.